# Сократить время между запросами API OpenWeatherMap

Tags: python, openweathermap

По умолчанию запрос погоды с их API, если не ошибаюсь, раз в 10 минут. На сайте пишут, что даже в бесплатном использовании доступно 60 запросов в минуту. Как уменьшить задержку между запросами с 10 минут, допустим, до минуты? если это вообще возможно

> python 3.12:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
import time
import threading

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('*****************')
...
    def cycle():
        mgr = owm.weather_manager()
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place('******************')
        while True:
            w = observation.weather
            wind = w.wind()['speed']
            temperature = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
            temperature_format = round(temperature, 1)
            weather = str.lower(w.detailed_status)
            cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
            ram_usage = round(int(psutil.virtual_memory().used) / 1073741824, 2)
            swap_usage = round(int(psutil.swap_memory().used) / 1073741824, 2)
            canvas.delete('cpu', 'ram', 'swap', 'weather', 'temp', 'wind', 'city')
            canvas.create_text(97, 10, anchor=CENTER, text=f'CPU: {str(cpu_usage)} % (неточное)', fill='white',
                               tags=['cpu'])
            canvas.create_text(97, 25, anchor=CENTER, text=f'RAM: {str(ram_usage)} ГБ', fill='white', tags=['ram'])
            canvas.create_text(97, 40, anchor=CENTER, text=f'SWAP: {str(swap_usage)} ГБ', fill='white', tags=['swap'])
            canvas.create_text(98, 60, anchor=CENTER, text=f'Погода: {weather}', fill='white', tags=['weather'])
            canvas.create_text(97, 75, anchor=CENTER, text=f'Температура: {temperature_format} °С', fill='white',
                               tags=['temp'])
            canvas.create_text(97, 90, anchor=CENTER, text=f'Ветер: {wind} м/с', fill='white', tags='wind')
            canvas.create_text(117, 135, anchor=NW, text='*********', font='Calibri 8', fill='white',
                               tags=['city'])
            time.sleep(1)

    threading.Thread(target=cycle, daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: Все верно, без подписки вы можете делать до 60 запросов в минуту и до 1 миллиона запросов в месяц. Про какие запросы в 10 минут вы говорите?

Comment: И лучше прямо код ваш покажите в вопросе. Может у вас там задержка прямо прописана. А мы ваш код не видим же.

Comment: @ZxNuClear раз в 10 минут это вроде стандартная задержка между запросами в их апи. В теории ее можно изменить

Comment: Так, и как ведёт себя данный код? Тут у вас запрос раз в секунду посылается. Почему вы пишете, что раз в 10 минут - запрос висит 10 минут или что или как? И, судя по всему, у вас `tkinter` используется для отрисовки, почему про это не упомянуто? Насколько я понимаю, вы пытаетесь рисовать в бесконечном цикле, а как получит управление сам `tkinter` при этом? Я так понимаю интерфейс будет просто висеть и ничего не будет отрисовываться. А, хотя это отдельный тред... Ну, в любом случае это не выглядит правильным стилем работы с `GUI`.

Comment: @Igor Я почитал, что у них на сайте написано. Это не задержка между запросами, а это промежуток обновления самих данных в `API`. Т.е. запрашивать чаще без толку, сами данные обновляются раз в 10 минут.

Comment: @CrazyElf, отрисовка через tkinter.canvas, задержка отрисовки - 1 секунда через time.sleep(1). Второй комментарий, напишите, пожалуйста, как ответ, дабы закрыть вопрос. Спасибо

Comment: @Igor Я понял, написал ответ уже )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3) написано:

> One Call API 3.0 is based on the proprietary OpenWeather Model and **is updated every 10 minutes**. Thus, in order to receive the most accurate and up-to-date weather data, we **recommend you request** One Call API 3.0 **every 10 minutes**.

В общем, сама модель, на которой базируется `OWM API`, обновляется раз в 10 минут, поэтому делать запросы чаще просто нет смысла - новые данные чаще чем раз в 10 минут там не появляются, а бесплатные запросы, число которых в день ограничено, будут при этом тратиться.